# Publishing Amazon AWS credentials for account with 1 permission

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an piece of code I want to live on a static website but I want it to pull the latest version of a file in an Amazon AWS S3 bucket to display a link for download. I'm not requiring the user to authenticate in any way with my site.

The API I'm using ([`aws-sdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) for javascript) requires credentials to perform any operation, even on a public bucket. My plan for listing the files is to create an IAM user that can only access a subfolder in this bucket through the following policy to do what I need:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfDLFolder",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cobstatic.com"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "dl/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this secure? Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can just make the file public and download it without `aws-sdk` by simply hitting its S3 URL.

Comment: @p4sh4 I should have specified in more detail that "pull the latest version" means to find the most recently edited version in a given subfolder and to use that.

Comment: In this case I'd say it is fine and secure enough. Don't think there is a better solution. Just make sure that you don't add any additional permissions to this user by accident. But if you're concerned about this, I'd minimise the risk by making all versions public and finding the recently edited version without depending on `aws-sdk`, for example based on the file name or some other mechanism in your code.

Comment: I think I have found a solution. If I use some well known name, I can set a metadata key value that then gets sent as an HTTP header (say, x-amz-meta-version) and use that to display the current version of the file using an HTTP HEAD request to get just the headers without getting the whole content. I should be able to do this with any metadata too!

Comment: Exposing credentials is a bad practice even if they are highly restricted.  AWS reportedly has algorithms looking for exposed credentials in the wild and they have been known to contact developers and advise them to invalidate  credentials that have been discovered.  Bucket listings are also an expensive API request, at > 10x the cost of `GET` or `HEAD`.